# SkyScanner API error when called by PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl, skyscanner

I did exactly as shown in the API documentation
http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList
but when i call it returns this error

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Cache-Control: private Content-Type: application/json Date: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 06:23:48 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 2 {}
```

and here is my code in PHP

```
<?
$url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/';
$data = array('apiKey' => 'de995438234178656329029769192274', 'country' => 'BR', 'currency' => 'BRL',
'locale' => 'pt-BR', 'originplace' => 'SDU-iata', 'destinationplace' => 'GRU-iata', 'outbounddate' => '2016-09-23', 
$headers = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
printf($result);
?>
```

any idea what is going wrong?

thanks in advance for any kind

Comment: did you forget the "adults" parameter?

Comment: Thank you for reply. But your answer does not make sense. What do you mean exactly "adults parameter"?

Comment: the documentation you refer to says the parameter "adults" is required, but I don't see it in your code.

Comment: No it's not it says that's if it's not set, it's set to 1 per default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think the PHP is sending the wrong request type, because the HTTP headers were being sent as an array (so defaults to 'multipart/formdata').  If you use http_build_query on that array, it is sent correctly as 'x-www-form-urlencoded'.

I've tidied things up, removed some duplication in the curl options, and correctly get a 201 response on your example now:

```
<?
$url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/';
$data = array('apiKey' => 'de995438234178656329029769192274', 'country' => 'BR', 'currency' => 'BRL',
'locale' => 'pt-BR', 'originplace' => 'SDU', 'destinationplace' => 'GRU', 'outbounddate' => '2016-09-23', 'locationschema' => 'Iata', 'adults' => 1);   
$httpdata = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $httpdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Hope that helps, I'll keep an eye on the thread in case of anything else - feel free to drop us a query or check the FAQs here: https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us

Comment: Thank you so much David. For sure it help me. But yet, after another whole day i can't find why we get 201 response instead the correct session key.

Comment: So that's documented too - the response has no content so the session key is in the response header.  Look out for the "Location" header value and it's in there... Hope that helps!